# virtual machine player to os x

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

i was looking for a virtual machine players that i can run in mac osx. I looked vmware website and virtualbox and they dont have binaries to mac osx. I have to do kernel based development and i dont want to develop in my own machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware and Virtualbox certainly do have OS X binaries. It's the second link in the list on the Virtualbox [Downloads](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) page, and should come up on the [VMware Fusion demo](https://www.vmware.com/tryvmware/?p=vmware-fusion&lp=1) download.

(Only for Intel Macs, of course... you can't virtualise x86 hardware on a PPC.)

If you really want a virtualisation solution for an OS X *guest* that's a trickier matter. Parallels can do it for OS X Server; other than that hackintosh is doable on VMware.

Comment: There's also Parallels for Mac OS X

Comment: i tried to access virtualbox link and i received 404. now its working